# Requesting help specifying which element to interact with. (Java w/Selenium)

Tags: java, selenium

The code from the page is as follows:

```
<td align="center" width="50%">

<input type="button" id="M_860735" value="Continue" class="entereclass" style="background-image: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial; background-color: rgb(244, 244, 244); width: 100px; visibility: hidden; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial; " onclick="this.disabled= true; this.value='Loading...'; M_3275409(1);"><br>

<input type="button" id="M_1723091" value="Continue" class="enterclass" style="background: #F4F4F4; width: 100px; margin-top: 3px; visibility: hidden;" onclick=" this.disabled= true; this.value='Loading...'; M_3275409(2);">
</td>

<td align="center" width="50%">

<input type="button" id="M_2802510" value="Continue" class="enterclass" style="background: #F4F4F4; width: 100px; visibility: hidden;" onclick="this.disabled= true; this.value='Loading...'; M_3275409(3);"><br>

<input type="button" id="M_1860441" value="Continue" class="enterclass" style="background-image: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin:n initial; background-clip: initial; background-color: rgb(244, 244, 244); width: 100px; margin-top: 3px; visibility: visible; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial; " onclick="this.disabled= true; this.value='Loading...'; M_3275409(4);">
</td>
```

I would like to be able to take each element and store the four IDs in temp variables to be used with each time I try to click.
(The ID's for the buttons are randomly generated, and the class of them cycle through three different choices ["enterclass", "forward", and "inputsubmit"])

All that I do to go through each of the classes and click the button when logging in is:

```
try{ driver.findElement(By.ByClassName.ByClass("enterclass")).click(); } catch {exception e {}
```

Then change the "enterclass" to the other options, and paste.

But I cannot do this here, as they are all the same.

Maybe instead of getting the IDs each time, I could have the program recognize that there are four, and try a click on each one?
(Again, not sure how to do that either, lol)

I am still new to Java, so I don't quite know the most proficient ways to do these things.

If anyone can help me, a reply would be greatly appreciated. ^_^

Thanks!
~ Ben King of Moria

UPDATE:
Fail...I figured it out. :P

I just did:

```
 try{ 
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[2]/center/table[13]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/input")).click();
     } catch(Exception e){}
     try{ 
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[2]/center/table[13]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/input[2]")).click();
     } catch(Exception e){}
     try{ 
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[2]/center/table[13]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/input")).click();
     } catch(Exception e){}
     try{ 
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[2]/center/table[13]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/input[2]")).click();
     } catch(Exception e){}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is a very long xpath. I would suggest instead getting all the 'input' elements on the page by using 'FindElements' instead of 'findElement' and then filtering through those by accessing their id's and such. Eg.

```
elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/input");
foreach(IWebElement e in elements)
{
    sting class = elements[0].getAttribute("class");
    if (class == "whatever")
        ;//do your stuff! :)
}
```

Outside of the xpath just looking ridiculously long, this is very unmaintainable. If there was to be even a slight UI change on the page your xpath could easily become incorrect. IMHO, it's better to get a subset of the pages elements and then sift through them logically. However, if it works it works! :)